# Qual é a expressão em inglês para se referir a uma pessoa que diz não querer uma coisa enquanto demonstra claramente querer muito?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, termos-em-inglês, gíria

No Brasil, é usado a gíria "cu doce" para se referir a tal ato, principalmente em **sedução**. Tentei encontrar uma expressão mais formal, mas só encontrei "negaça", que ninguém parece usar e que aparentemente não tem tradução para o inglês.

Comment: referir a tal ato.....que ato? Você não definiu a expressão.

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar, nem todos os brasileiros têm o mesmo entendimento quanto ao significado de "fazer cu doce". Haja vista o número de definições diferentes que encontramos no Google.  Entendo "fazer cu doce" como "fazer-se de difícil", demonstrar que não quer alguma coisa quando realmente quer. ([referência](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer_cu_doce))

A primeira expressão que me vem à mente, e que se assemelha a "fazer cu doce" em inglês, é "play hard to get". Outras opções seriam "use coy tricks" ou "play coy".

> - [Definition of play hard to get](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play%20hard%20to%20get)
>   : to pretend that one is not interested in having a romantic or sexual relationship with someone in order to make that person more attracted to one

> - [**coy**](https://www.google.com/search?q=coy+definition&oq=coy+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i19l6j0i19i22i30l3.4124j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - adjective - (especially with reference to a woman) making a pretense of shyness or modesty that is intended to be alluring.

from Google Books:

1. "We use the dramatic style to elicit information by playing dumb , to attract attention by playing coy , and to command respect by playing the strong , silent type."
2. "The boy was obviously interested , but playing coy and hard to get."
3. "She hadn ' t agreed right away , not because she was playing coy , but because her brain had insisted she give voice to a list of reasonable objections."
4. "a detailed guideline which consists of 35 rules on ways a woman can play hard to get when she meets the man of her dreams."
5. "These guides encourage women to play hard to get, not to say “I love you” first,"

Comment: corrige aí a homófona pt-BR *têm :)

Comment: Mas nesse caso não é quando a pessoa se finge de dificil e sim quando demonstra querer e nega apenas verbalmente. Outra expressão em pt-BR seria "fazer manha".

Comment: @Sorb  Mas "play hard to get" também serve, pois não traz a conotação de demonstrar que quer ou não.  É como fazer-se de rogado, a pessoa pode estar demonstrando que quer que insistam mas também pode não estar demonstrando.

Comment: @Sorb  E você só pode afirmar com convicção que alguém está "playing hard to get", se a pessoa demonstrar por gestos ou expressão facial, que quer.  Caso contrário é sempre uma suposição. "Look at her face! She's playing hard to get".